# Change default location of voice recorder files

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am using the built-in voice recorder in my Android App. Is there a way I can change the default location of recorded files? They are stored in the "Sound" folder in SD Card. I want to store them in a different folder. How do I do it, if that's even possible?

Below is a simple code for calling the built-in Android voice recorder App.

```
Button startRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);

    startRecording.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent recordIntent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION); 

            startActivityForResult(recordIntent, REQUEST_CODE_RECORD);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

well you will have to allow the file to be recorded using where ever the default location and file name that are used and then move the file. 
you could do something like this in your **onActivityResult**:

```
   @Override protected void onActivityResult(
         int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch (requestCode) {
      case REQUEST_CODE_RECORD:
         if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Sound recorder does not support EXTRA_OUTPUT
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
               String filePath = getAudioPathFromUri(uri);
               copyFile(filePath);
               getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);  
               (new File(filePath)).delete();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   private String getAudioPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
      Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
            .query(uri, null, null, null, null);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA);
      return cursor.getString(index);
   }

   private void copyFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
      Files.copy(new File(fileName), 
         new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName));
   }
}
```